# Gridview: Get a value from cell of database data table where ID=rowEditIndex , how?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

On GridView1 RowDataBound how can I get something like this :

```
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Column AND DataTableID=RowEditIndex.
```

I'm trying to get the value of a cell from dataTable of the current editing row . so he needs to get the value from a certain cell of datTable of the current editing row of the gridview.

I need the correct sql statment and I need it in rowDataBound gridview cuz I have another code there.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using data keys on the GridView, like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="SomeID, SomeOtherColumn" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" ...>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    int someID = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex]["SomeOtherColumn"];

    //do whatever you need to do with the value
}
```

**EDIT**: Here's an example of how you can access a data key in the `RowUpdating` event:

```
protected void TaskGridView_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    var someValue = GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex]["SomeOtherColumn"].ToString();
}
```

You can also access the value through the `DataItem` property in the `RowDataBound` event:

```
int someID = (int)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "SomeID");
```

Comment: item.rowindex doesn't exists in rowdatabound :(

Comment: Sorry, I corrected my answer. It should be `e.Row.RowIndex` or `e.Row.DataItem`, depending on which solution you're using.

Comment: good so with that code I get the edit id row of the column , now , can you tell me what would be the correct statment : SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE Column AND ID=someID" it's correct?

Comment: Do you need to query the database from within the `RowDataBound` event?

Comment: Yes , so I can get the value if the ID of current edited row == datatTable row from where I get the value.

Comment: Are you trying to get a value from the same `DataTable` when the ID matches?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you shouldn't need any kind of a select statement. Just grab the value you need from the `DataItem` bound to the row, or add the column as a data key.

Comment: I want to get the value from a column of the edited row , and the value is in data table

Comment: Yes, but the `DataTable` is bound to the GridView, and therefore accessible through the GridView directly. Just add the column as a datakey and you'll be able to access the value.

Comment: ok done I added the column I want to get the value and I added this in row data bound string someID = (string)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "ColumnName");
            Label1.Text = someID;  , and I'm not geting the value , I know I should add something like that In updating event but I want to get it in row databound

Comment: Ok I understand but I want to get the value in the row data bound not updating

Comment: It should be working, but you can try giving the data key solution a shot too. I know these solutions work, so we just need to figure out where the disconnect is.

Comment: @InaaInzii: It still applies. Look at the example where it shows you how to add a data key and access the value from the `RowDataBound` event.

Comment: yeah but I need to get the value in the rowdatabound to compare it with another value

Comment: done I found how , thank you but now I have a problem , If I update the row with the update button of the gridview , nothing is updated.

Comment: There could be any number of reasons for that. Revise the question and post your update logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Linq;

...
...


var myValue = myDataTable.AsEnumerable().where (r=>r["MYColumn"].ToString()==RowEditIndex.ToString()).select(a=>a["MYColumn"].ToString())
```

Comment: hmm myDataTable should be? and is there any chance to make it easy to understand please? r->r , numerable , I never used. thank you